# Windows Phone HttpClient PostAsync returns before response

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Windows phone app piece of code returns before the server sends the response. I know, I need to call it synchronously but I tried with various options and it failed. Below is the piece of code

```
string finalUri = ServerConstants.serverName + "PCUserSignUP";
string postString = "email=" + uEmail + "&password=" + uPass;
Debug.WriteLine(finalUri);
signUpReq.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
//signUp_result = await signUpReq.GetStringAsync(finalUri);
var response = await signUpReq.PostAsync(finalUri, new StringContent(postString)).ConfigureAwait(true);
//signUp_result = strResult;
//Debug.WriteLine("Result=" + strResult);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Debug.WriteLine("response body="+responseBody);
var userJsonObj = (signUpResponseJSON)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<signUpResponseJSON>(responseBody);
if(userJsonObj.response.Equals("success",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    UserProfile.getUserProfile().updatePcId(userJsonObj.pcid);
    signUp_result = userJsonObj.pcid;
}
//UserProfile.
```

I tried with .Result and ConfigureAwait(false), nothing worked...How to fix this. It was working well until I was using GET but the moment I moved to PostAsync it stopped working and also Am I using the StringContent correctly?

Comment: Sorry to sound potentially condescending, but is your method definitely marked with the `async` modifier?

Comment: I am using await but still the response is null, if I try the URL in browser in POST it works well..

Comment: One other indication is, if I add .Result in the postasync statement, it never returns. Its keep on running...

Comment: I doubt, my querystring is not properly passed, anyways to check it?

Comment: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 14:36:42 GMT
  X-Cache: MISS from proxy-server5-int2
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 0
}
This is the response, what is Miss from proxy server? is it saying somehting?

Comment: Will this code work if the response is JSON?